# How can we edit our tags?

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks

I went a little crazy adding tags that I was interested in and now I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of some.  How is this done?

Comment: If you're referring to your "favorite" tags, you should be able to click on the "edit" link and get a clickable x on each tag.

Comment: I *think* I'm referring to my "favorite" tags. When you go into your account page they follow your bio.  I can't find an "edit" option for them - the only edit on the page takes me into my bio.  If I hover over the tags there is an option to subscribe but nothing that allows me to delete it.

Comment: The edit link is just to the right of the "favorite tags" caption.

Comment: I see.  Ok I only have two "favorite" tags. And I see now how to edit them (thanks!)  Are the tags that show up on our profile page related to questions that we have answered? (and that's why you can't edit them?)

Comment: Two whole tags.  Wow, that is crazy.

Comment: Yeah.. I have no idea where it was I was actually adding tags.  I'm slowly figuring things out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your favourite tags the same way you add them. Your list of favourite tags will look something like this:

> [image]

Click on the edit link, and you should be able to add new tags as well as remove them. To remove one, just click on the little cross shown on them.

> [image]

That should remove it.

> Are the tags that show up on our profile page related to questions that we have answered?

The tags that show up on your profile page are related to your activity within those tags and what score you got for them. Those can't be edited, except for becoming more or less active within a tag.